# How to get double-click time interval value programmatically on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system, mouse, double-click

I'm looking to programmatically get double click time interval value from `Linux OS` setting.

Windows has a Windows function called `GetDoubleClickTime` which does something similar [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646258(v=vs.85).aspx).

I'm looking for a `Linux` equivalent for this.

Comment: It's not part of the OS on Linux. It probably depends on the window toolkit used by the application.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me since it's part of Mouse settings in the OS. I'm assuming that this value is saved somewhere in the OS settings but I can't seem to find a way to retrieve it.

I tried to see if there's an xinput property for the same but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I think it depends on the operating system and display or window manager used by the distro or user. See, for example, [HOWTO: General mouse customization, including double click](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=316441) on the Ubuntu forums.

Comment: The window system isn't even part of the OS on Linux. It's a hodgepodge of the X Window System and different libraries. If you use GTK, you set it in `~/.gtkrc-2.0`, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/563072/mouse-double-click-time-is-too-short-in-lubuntu?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa